# (PyQt6/PySide6) Creating widgets inline generates access violation and crashes silently

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

Taking the official PySide6 example in
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_widgets_layouts_borderlayout.html

The original code works without a problem, showing the UI as stated in the webpage. However, if we inline the 5 local variables in `Window.__init__` returned by `create_label`, namely replacing code between Line #218 to Line #232 with

```
        border_layout.addWidget(self.create_label("North"), Position.North)
        border_layout.addWidget(self.create_label("West"), Position.West)
        border_layout.addWidget(self.create_label("East 1"), Position.East)
        border_layout.addWidget(self.create_label("East 2"), Position.East)
        border_layout.addWidget(self.create_label("South"), Position.South)
```

The program silently crashes without showing anything. Tracing `%errorlevel%` from batch console returns error code `C0000005` meaning access violation. Moreover, calling `gc.disable()` does not help. This is reproducible on both PyQt6 and PySide6. Should be reproducible on PyQt5 as well.

It looks quite counterintuitive to me that inlining a few local variables would make such a difference. I'm also wondering whether there's a way to at least have some error traceback when this situation occurs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The example appears to be a somewhat literal translation of the orignal C++ code. It seems fairly clear that there's going to be nothing holding a reference to the labels at the point where `setLayout` is called in your revised version. The `QWidgetItem` won't take ownership, so it's up to the caller to make sure the labels are kept alive on the Python side. I would suggest making this change: `def create_label(self, text): label = QLabel(text, self) ... etc` ( and there's no need for this to be a static method).

Comment: Yes setting a parent in constructor does work around this problem. I also tried having an external dict holding reference to every QLabel created and that also helps. It's just that this silent crash happens on such a common use case, making me wonder the reason causing it. After reading your comments I'm starting to wonder if there's some reference management done from C++ side but somewhat overlooked when ported to Python. Waiting for someone to confirm or correct me on this.

Comment: There's no mystery here at all. The Python garbage-collector will usually delete objects as soon as they go out of scope (if there's no other references held for them). That is completely normal and expected ***in Python***. But Qt is written in C++ and knows nothing about Python. If you pass it a pointer to an object that Python has already deleted, a fatal error will occur if it tries to access the memory at that location (i.e. an access violation will occur, and it will dump core). Setting a parent isn't a "work-around" - it's one of the documented ways to keep a reference. So just use it.

Comment: PS: the Qt docs will usually explicitly state whether an API takes ownership of the objects passed to it or not. This affects both C++ and Python, so you must pay attention to it. I suppose most Python coders will find managing memory in this way quite foreign, and they might expect PyQt to do it all for them. And to a large extent it does - but doing more would entail a significant performance cost that would affect ***all*** PyQt code, so a compromise must be made. If you're new to PyQt, you might find this unsettling at first, but it's really not a big deal - you'll soon get used to it.